# Flexslider arrows not displayed properly

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, navigation

I've been stuck with this problem for some time, and can't seem to find an answer, so I decided to ask straight.

I am using the Flexslider plugin to display multiple images on a site, however, the arrows navigation that displays when hovering the image is off. The arrow is cut off at the top, and the text underneath it that is supposed to be completely hidden is partly showing. Here is a screen shot of the problem:

[image]

I tried tinkering with the CSS, but I just can't figure it out. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.flex-direction-nav a`:

```
.flex-direction-nav a  { 
    display: block; 
    width: 40px; 
    height: 40px; 
    margin: -20px 0 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; z-index: 10; 
    overflow: hidden; /* Remove this line */
    opacity: 0; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease; 
    transition: all .3s ease; 
}
```

If you need to alter or remove the text that shows up by default for 'Previous' and 'Next', consult the options documentation 'Tailor to Your Needs' for the plugin here: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Following that, just update the settings for:

```
prevText: "Previous",    //String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
nextText: "Next",        //String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item
```

Comment: This works, but shows both the arrows and the text. I would like to have only the arrows shown and the text hidden..

Comment: Do you have access to the markup? The text is rendered in html, so you may be able to remove it at the source.

Comment: The text is added through jQuery. I am a jQuery newbie, so I don't know how to go about it. But I think it's supposed to be there, just hidden. Basically, I just need to somehow move the arrows a bit more down. But can't find how. My original thought was to play around with the margin that is currently set to -20px, but it just moves the whole navigation..

Comment: I think you'll need to locate the point in the script where that text is being applied and remove there. Alternatives to this would be JS hacks ran after the fact. One path to moving text off-screen with CSS is to use: 'text-indent: -9999px;' but that also moves the arrows in this case. I'd just open the plugin code and search for the strings 'Next' and 'Previous', and remove.

Comment: I actually did that, but it seems that the text itself is employed in the functionality of the plugin..

Comment: OK, I found the options listing for your plugin, which when coupled with the CSS update above, should get you to the solution. Updating my answer now.

Comment: Thank you so much! Apparently, I deleted a wrong piece of text before, silly me. Problem solved!

Answer (score 28):

You can also add `line-height` to solve it:

```
.flex-direction-nav a  {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

PS: It seems like a Flexslider bug, that it does not work properly with default settings.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow, which is a font, is too large for its container.

Just add this CSS, it will reduce the size of the font, and in turn, fix the cut off issue.

```
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
    font-family: "flexslider-icon";
    font-size: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '\F001';
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

Add this into your CSS and it will override the default settings for flexslider

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by changing the font size of "flexslider-icon" in the flexslider CSS (around line 70 in flexslider.css).

It seems to be set to 40px at default, but changing it to 30px has worked perfectly on two websites I'm building.

Answer (score 0):

Open your "jquery.flexslider.js" file and search `"// Primary Controls"` at line 1125 (approximately). You'd find,

```
// Primary Controls
controlNav: true,
directionNav: true,
prevText: "Previous",
nextText: "Next",
```

Here, you need to remove the next and prev text, and save it again.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
.flex-direction-nav li a{
      height:50px; 
}
```

This overrides the default css