# Adding Flexslider to a Wordpress Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, flexslider

I want to add a flex slider to a Wordpress Child theme but it does not work. I have been trying for hours and would appreciate some help.
Here is the site:
http://dev.electricalenergy.se/

In my Child Theme, I have added:
1. a CSS folder with flexslider.css
2. a js folder with jquery.flexslider.js
3. function.php with the following script

```
<?php
// FLEXSLIDER
function flexslider() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

        // Enqueue FlexSlider JavaScript
        wp_register_script('jquery_flexslider', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery_flexslider');

        // Enqueue FlexSlider Stylesheet        
        wp_register_style( 'flexslider-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider-style' );

        // FlexSlider custom settings       
        add_action('wp_footer', 'flexslider_settings');

        function flexslider_settings() { ?>         
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
                });
            </script>
        <?php 
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'flexslider');
```

4. at last, I duplicated index.php from the parent Theme and added

   ```
   <div id="primary" class="content-area">
   <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

           <!-- Flexslider demo content -->

           <div class="flexslider">
               <ul class="slides">
                   <li>
                       <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6213/6256961398_a484813abe_b.jpg" />
                       <p class="flex-caption">Caption goes here</p>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6025/6012928351_d643e5a404_b.jpg" />
                       <p class="flex-caption">Caption goes here</p>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6126/6007110789_bd7faaaa79_b.jpg" />
                       <p class="flex-caption">Caption goes here</p>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5159/5874760659_de4c00d585_b.jpg" />
                       <p class="flex-caption">Caption goes here</p>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>

           <!-- END Flexslider demo content -->
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You code is correct, but the css is empty and the js is not loaded:

404

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.electricalenergy.se/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js?ver=4.5"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.electricalenergy.se/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/css/flexslider.css?ver=4.5"

Put the css/js files of flexslider in your parent theme directory or [follow this](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2014/11/03/loading-parent-styles-for-child-themes).

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you for your time! How did you get these error messages? they are actually meaningful. Do you know why the half of the arrows on flexslider are visible?

Comment: Use firebug for firefox, or open your browser console for errors message. For flexslider, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817603/flexslider-arrows-not-displayed-properly